# Laravel, dynamical urls in css

Tags: css, laravel

I've in laravel resource/sass/app.scss. In a such code:

```
.card {
    ..
    background: url(/img/plus-green.png) no-repeat;
    ..
}
```

Is it possible to make an url according to website location e.g `url(<?=url('/imgs/img.png')?>)`, that if website is in my localhost xampp http://localhost/myproj/public/imgs/img.png or in a live https://example.com/imgs/img.png . I'm looking for make dynamical urls to css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ***use relative paths*** instead of absolute paths.

**[Read more here on relative vs absolute paths.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/645186)**

You should change your code from:

```
.card {
    ..
    background: url(/img/plus-green.png) no-repeat;
    ..
}
```

to

```
.card {
    ..
    background: url(../img/plus-green.png) no-repeat;
    ..
}
```

Comment: The compilation makes "images/minus.png", how to do that it makes "myproj/public/imgs/minus.png"??

Comment: I need absolute paths in CSS. The laravel scss compiles wrong them.

Comment: @user2301515 I made a slight edit, check it now.